# How to integrate nancy with asp.net Form based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, nancy

We are in process to migrate our asp.net based application to nancy, as Application is quite big, so we have decided to make application hybrid & migrate it to nancy page by page.

Now we have a nancy login screen, using which we need to do asp.net form authentication as well. Can someone guide us how can we authenticate user with asp.net form based authentication in nancy code.
We are planning to use stateless authentication on nancy side.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

We are having a nancy login page to validated user credentials

**1. Login Module -**

```
 Post["/login"] = p =>
            {
// Verify user crdentials first
// Success, create non-persistent authentication cookie.
                    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(credentials.tbUser, false);
                    var cookie = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(credentials.tbUser, false);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
return Response.AsRedirect("~/listRequest.aspx"); // used Nancy's redirect model to navigate to another page 
}
```

**2. Global.asax -**

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            FormsIdentity fIdent = application.Context.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
            if (fIdent != null) **// It always returns null even after ".ASPXAUTH" cookie is successfully created**
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = fIdent.Ticket;  // to see if the ticket exists
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-authentication

Comment: **@matjaz**, thanks for link, but it will not help in our case, we want to use Asp.net Form based authentication primarily till the time our application is in hybrid mode, once we will be fully migrated to nancy we can look for other single-sign on options available

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas I have not tested but seems likely to be is to use the LoginWithoutRedirect method of Nancy.Authentication.Forms.

Your application will manage authentication cookies for ASP.NET and authentication cookies for Nancy Forms at the same time.